# Unused parameters in Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, suppress-warnings

If one has no intention of using a parameter in C++, one simply omits the name of the variable but keeps the type in the function declaration. Doing so is a light-weight method to signal to the compiler that one intends not to use a given parameter.

Is this possible to replicate in Java?

The scenario is this: I would like not to flood my code with `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` for every single button listener (because button listeners most often ignore the `View v` they receive), and yet I would like to be warned in general about the silly mistake of, say, not initializing a member variable by a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything like the C++ option but you could extend/implement your button listener and add a new method without the parameter and have that method called in the original event method. This way you will only have to suppress warnings once.

`public void someEvent(Parameter p) {
   someEvent();
}`

public void someEvent() {
}

Answer (score 1):

In addition to creating an adapter like @Farzad suggested, you might want to also check your compiler settings in your IDE. For example, I use Eclipse and there are error/warning compiler settings under Window->Preferences->Java Compiler->Errors/Warnings.  Within that dialog you can set UnnecessaryCode->Value of parameter is not used->Ignore in overriding and implementing methods.

Having that option checked automatically ignores those unused params when they are from a method that you are implementing/overriding such as in your listener case.  I generally find that to be sufficient without needing to create an adapter.